# Why doesn't `posts_path` work in `rails console`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does `link_to 'Back', posts_path` work in ERB but `posts_path` doesn't work in the console?

```
$ rails console
irb(main):005:0> posts_path
NameError: undefined local variable or method `posts_path' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add context of `app` in console.

```
app.posts_path
app.get app.posts_path
app.response
app.response.body
```